# How to replace multiple characters in a string with other multiple characters (another string) without replacing other ocurrences?

Tags: c#, string

I'm making a console application for IP assignment where a user simply enters the number of networks, the number of hosts per network and the initial network IP address, and this generates the full IP assignment table.

My biggest issue right now is that say I have a string with "172.16.0.0".

I want to grab the 0 at the end, convert it to an int, add a certain number of hosts (say, 0 + 512), and if it goes over 255, I want it to instead grab the previous 0 and replace it with a 1 instead then test it again. But I'm mostly having issues with replacing the numbers in the initial string. Since strings aren't mutable, I obviously have to make a new string with the change, but I can't see how to do this.

I've so far tried finding the index where the change will be made using the string.split function and indexof and making that an int variable called datIndex. Then I change the "172.16.0.0" string to a character array, then tried swapping the character in the previously defined index, however this limits me to a single character, which wouldn't work for a number with more than one digit. Also tried using stringbuilder but the stringbuilder object seems to be a char type so I end up in the same place, can't equal the value in the index I want to change to the new number.

```
string test = "172.16.0.0";
int datIndex = test.IndexOf(test.Split('.')[2]);
char[] c = test.ToCharArray();

c[datIndex] = '201'; //Not possible because more than one digit

//Also tried the following

datIndex = test.IndexOf(test.Split('.')[2]);
         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(test);
         sb[datIndex] = '201'; //Cannot implicitly convert type string to char
            string temp2 = sb.ToString();
test = temp2; //Changed string
```

In this example, I'd like to change the penultimate "0" in the "172.16.0.0" string to a "201" (this number would be obtained by a sum of two numbers so ideally they'd both first be integers).

However with both methods I've tried, I can't fit a number bigger than one digit into that index.

Comment: How about using an IP address parsing library like the [IPAddressRange Class Library](https://github.com/jsakamoto/ipaddressrange/)?

Comment: I actually had no idea there was an IP address parsing library, I'll definitely check it out. Would there be another way to do this though? (just in case I eventually need to do it with non-IP address strings) I've heard about regex, do you know how that would be to be able to replace the '0' after the second period?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is maybe what you are looking for:

```
string ip = "127.16.0.0";
string ipNumbers = ip.Split('.');

int a = int.Parse (ipNumbers[0]);
int b = int.Parse (ipNumbers[1]);
int c = int.Parse (ipNumbers[2]);
int d = int.Parse (ipNumbers[3]);

//now you have in a,b,c and d all the ip numbers, do the math with them and then do this:

ip = $"{a}.{b}.{c}.{d}";
```